# Nginx caches upstream node resolved by an elastic load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, nginx, ip, load-balancing

I have an nginx AWS EC2 instance that forwards requests to an elastic load balancer (ELB) that is maintained by an auto scaling group (ASG).
 Now, these instances behind the elastic load balancer are born in and out of existence depending on the load on the instance that is set to 80% in the auto scaling group properties. 
Problem is that, this property cannot be changed and these new instances spin up with a new ip. 
But, nginx has cached the old IP it resolved before, for the previous version of this instance.
 We have to manually restart nginx everytime this happens and debugging takes time when I'm not around as well. We cannot use crontabs as we need a robust fix for this, kinda like a root cause fix.
Suggestions, anyone? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why do you use both nginx and an elastic load balancer? Normally you would only use the ELB. And if the instances are behind the ELB, why is nginx connecting to them? There isn't enough information here to answer the question (and it probably belongs on ServerFault anyway).

Comment: More information is needed like @kdgregory said but you could use an ALB to direct instances as target groups instead and not worry about the IP cache issue with nginx.